# How to get access to the json label as well as the value in an ExtJS grid?

Tags: extjs

I would like to have every value of a record populated in a grid for viewing but have no idea how to do that.

For example if the JSON looks like below I want to be able to have firstName, lastName and age in the first column and the associated values in corresponding rows in the second column.

```
{
   "people": [
        {"firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "age": 23}
    ]
}
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Despite various comments online about tpl being used only for iterating over array items I saw a video from sencha's 2010 convention using tpl specifically for one item and a number of subitems so .. with that in mind I thought maybe these threads might help in devising a solution: [xtemplate as xslt - wishful thinking](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?8025-XTemplate-New-Features-%28was-SuperTemplate-Feature-Request%29) and [creating an html table then grid'ifying it](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Ext-JS/CreateagridwithfromanexistingunformattedHTMLtable.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to set columns to your grid:

```
columns: [
                {header: 'firstName',  dataIndex: 'firstName',flex:1},
                {header: 'lastName',   dataIndex: 'lastName',  flex:1},
                {header: 'age',        dataIndex: 'age',flex:1}
        ],
```

then you need to define a model and a store:

```
Ext.define('gridModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
   {name: 'firstName', type:'string'},
   {name: 'lastName', type:'int'},
   {name: 'age', type:'string'}
]
```

});

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model: 'gridModel',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : 'url of your json',
    reader:{ 
        type:'json',
        root: 'people'          
    }
},
autoLoad:true
```

});

and your data should be in View. And define your store in grid: (store: myStore)

Cheers!

Comment: I am looking for a way to dynamically extract the label name from the json so I can say: for every property give me the property name ("firstName") and the property value ("Jane").